# How do I batch trim images 50% to the left with automator?

Tags: macos, automator, image-editing

I know I can batch trim images with automator for 50% horizontal, but then it get's trimmed on both sides... I need it to get 50% trimmed on just the left/right side.

Comment: If not, is there another free way to accomplish this?

Comment: So, you mean that you want to cut off the left-hand sides of a batch of images?

Comment: Yes, batch cut off 50% from the left side once. And with other images cut off 50% from the right side.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Automator; I'd use bash (on the command-line) for this sort of thing.

If you have ImageMagick installed (you should be able to get it from [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)), you can [use convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) to cut off one side or another of an image.

This will give you the left-hand side of the image (so it will cut off the right half):

```
convert input.png -crop 50%x100%+0+0 output.png
```

[image: No cropping] becomes [image: Left-hand side]

This will give you the right-hand side (cut off the left half of the image):

```
convert input.png -gravity east -crop 50%x100%+0+0 output.png
```

[image: No cropping] becomes [image: Right-hand side]

To act on every file ending with `.png` in a given directory, you can put it in a bash *for* loop:

```
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "${f%.*}-cropped.png"; done
```

To do so recursively (every `*.png` in the working directory, and every `*.png` in any sub-directories), use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar; for f in **/*.png; do convert "$f" -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "${f%.*}-cropped.png"; done
```

All of these will create a separate output file (in these examples, for every `file.png` there will be created a `file-cropped.png`). To work on files without creating a separate output, use [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) (the companion tool of `convert`). Of course, this **will over-write your existing files**, so be careful in its use. Mogrify is able to take multiple inputs from the command-line, so there is no need to use a *for* loop here:

```
mogrify -crop 50%x100%+0+0 *.png
##  Recursively:
shopt -s globstar; mogrify -crop 50%x100%+0+0 **/*.png
```

*If* you are working with a truly huge number of files (thousands), the above globs may choke; in that case, you should use `find`:

```
##  For convert:
find . -type f -name '*.png' -execdir bash -c 'convert "$0" -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "${0%.*}-cropped.png"' '{}' \;

##  For mogrify:
find . -type f -name '*.png' -execdir mogrify -crop 50%x100%+0+0 '{}' \;
```

You can put any of this stuff into a bash script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "${f%.*}-cropped.png"; done
exit 0
```

Or, a nicer-looking version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.png; do
  convert "$f" -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "${f%.*}-cropped.png"
done
exit 0
```

...save that in a plaintext file called something like `crop-left.sh` and set it as executable:

```
chmod u+x crop-left.sh
```

To use it from the command-line, it would be

```
./crop-left.sh
```

I don't know how to fit this into Automator, since I've never used that program, but it probably can be done.

Comment: Great answer. Automator only allows you to specify the crop percentage, but you can't tell it *where* to crop, so I'm not sure if there's a built in way. Of course you can run these commands from within Automator's *Run Shell Script* action as well.

Comment: Can I save this as some sort of application, that I just have to click one button? (I can save Automator workflows as applications. Is it possible with command line stuff? ^^)

Comment: How to save this as a Shell Script that I can integrate it in automator? And if I do save it as shell script, can I refrain from specifying a folder in the shell script, so I can specify the folder in Automator?

Comment: You certainly can save it into a shell script - make sure that the first line of the file is `#! /usr/bin/env bash`, and then just paste whichever line you prefer to use, and set it as executable (from the command-line: `chmod u+x scriptname.sh` - replace scriptname.sh with whatever you want to call the script). Unfortunately, I've never used Automator, so I don't know how to integrate shell scripts into it - hopefully @slhck or someone with that knowledge will come along and tell how to do it.

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured out you also can use Pixelmator's automater recipes to crop from one side!